# How to test a validation with conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, rspec2

How should I test a validation with a conditional like this:

```
validates :age, :numericality => true, :if => :age?
```

This is what I have for now:

```
before(:each) do
  @attr = { :age => "30" }
end

it "should require a age if present" do
   Model.new(@attr.merge(:age => "foo").should_not be_valid
end
```

And the error message is:

`expected valid? to return false, got true`

But doing this, the `if`is not evaluated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you actually written a method called "age?" ?

I think what you're trying to do is actually covered by:

```
 validates :age, :numericality => true, :allow_nil => true
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `:allow_nil => true` instead of the `:if` condition?